# Is there a way to hook resource requests on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, if I have this

```
<img src="my_picture.jpg">
```

or

```
<div style="background-image:url('my_picture.jpg')"></div>
```

then is it possible to hook those resource requests? By default the browser would try and load page url + /my_picture.jpg but I want to handle that request myself inside js and give the browser the data that it should use as this file.

Also those 2 are examples of loading images but I mean for basically all file loads, is there a hook for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "hook"? Do you mean React's hooks?

Comment: @JackBashford I mean hook as in a general programming term, like partially or completely replacing default functionality of an environment.

Comment: Are you referring to lazy loading?

Comment: So, like monkey patching in JS? (not seen the term "hook" used outside of React before). Or do you mean lazy loading? If so, there's a good library [here](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload).

Comment: @JackBashford I suppose yes, monkey patching would cover it. I've seen hooks in various contexts in almost all languages, for instance in c++ you would hook dll loads to inject code or in drupal you would hook event handlers to do your own thing before or after default handlers run.

Comment: You might be able to do this with an extension, which has privileged access to certain browser internals, but I'm pretty sure that ordinary Javascript on a page won't cut it.